# How to select the compatible USB to SPI IC Programmer?

Tags: spi, firmware

I built an image of Coreboot (open source firmware) and wanted to flash it on the Minnowboard Max. SF100 is compatible to do the job (as described in [this](https://minnowboard.org/tutorials/updating-firmware-via-spi-flash-programmer) article). However, I want to be clear on the compatibility and possibly want cheaper alternatives.

SPI protocol is the standard one, so I believe except the pin layout exposed by the development board SPI IC connector, the underlying job must be same for all the SPI IC programmers. But I am still not sure.

What should I take care of, so that I am sure that the programmer will be compatible with my development board.

**EDIT**

I searched regarding the BIOS EEPROM chip on my SBC and I got to know its an SPI based chip. At the same time, I also came across people using Raspberry Pi / Arduino with [flashrom](https://www.flashrom.org) to flash BIOS on their laptops and motherboards. So technically I should also be able to flash BIOS using a SPI master device (say raspberry pi) instead of buying dedicated costly devices (provided I follow correct connections and voltage levels recommended for the chip).

I see no technical limitations with this approach. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There are no criteria in the body of your question that could be used to answer this - making people look up the details of your question to find out what you are asking is not how this site is supposed to work.  Something like an STM32 blue pill can do the task with flashrom though flashrom is painfully slow and pedantic by design intent because it is meant to be used once on a valuable system.  Making the electrical connections, voltage differences,  and getting the target processor out of the way are the standard concerns.

Comment: Your edit seems to overlook what the above comment pointed out a week ago.  While flashrom can probably perform the needed operations you must still consider the electrical and physical concerns, the necessary details for which are still missing from your question.